# frequencies counting

Tags: r

I have a situation like this:
df

```
List      Count 
R472        1   
R472        1   
R472        2 
R472        2       
R845        1   
R845        2   
R845        2
....       ...
```

I would like the following output:

df

```
List           freq_of_number1   freq_of_number2 
R472                  2                 2   
R845                  1                 2
....
```

Any idea about?
Thnks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `aggregate`:

```
d <- read.table(text="List      Count 
R472        1   
R472        1   
R472        2 
R472        2       
R845        1   
R845        2   
R845        2", header=TRUE)

aggregate(Count ~ List, data=d, FUN=table)

#   List Count.1 Count.2
# 1 R472       2       2
# 2 R845       1       2
```

EDIT:

The above code works in the case you provided and since you've accepted the answer, I assume it works for your larger case as well, but this simple answer will fail if any entry in `List` is missing one of the numbers in `Count`. For the more general case:

```
DF <- read.table(text="List      Count 
R472        1   
R472        1   
R472        2 
R472        2       
R845        1   
R845        2   
R845        2
R999        2", header=TRUE)

f <- function(x) {
    absent <- setdiff(unique(DF$Count), x)
    ab.count <- NULL
    if (length(absent) > 0) {
        ab.count <- rep(0, length(absent))
        names(ab.count) <- absent
    } 
    result <- c(table(x), ab.count)
    result[order(names(result))]
}
aggregate(Count ~ List, data=d, FUN=f)

#   List Count.1 Count.2
# 1 R472       2       2
# 2 R845       1       2
# 3 R999       0       1
```

EDIT 2:

Just saw @JasonMorgan's answer. Go accept that one.

Answer (score 3):

The `table` function doesn't work?

```
> with(DF, table(List, Count))
      Count
List   1 2
  R472 2 2
  R845 1 2
```

Update: Per Brandon's comment, this will work as well if you prefer not to use `with`:

```
> table(DF$List, DF$Count)
```

Comment: `table()` is all you need. `with` is unnecesary.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a more efficient way to do it, but here's one idea

```
DF <- read.table(text='List      Count 
R472        1   
R472        1   
R472        2 
R472        2       
R845        1   
R845        2   
R845        2', header=TRUE)



Freq <- lapply(split(DF, DF$Count), function(x) aggregate(.~ List, data=x, table ))
counts <- do.call(cbind, Freq)[, -3]
colnames(counts) <- c('List', 'freq_of_number1', 'freq_of_number2')
counts
List freq_of_number1 freq_of_number2
1 R472               2               2
2 R845               1               2
```